# How to call the scalar "curl" of a vector field in a plane?

Tags: reference-request, notation, vector-analysis, differential-operators, curl

I cannot find any standard name or notation for the analog of curl of a vector field in an oriented Euclidean plane.

There is this operator that to a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ given in the standard Cartesian coordinates as $(F_x, F_y)$ associates the scalar field $\partial_xF_y - \partial_yF_x$. How should this operator be called and denoted?

Comment: I have seen this called $curl_z$ and $rot$. If I can find where, I'll add it as an answer below.

Comment: @TomKern, thanks, but to the best of my knowledge, $\operatorname{rot}$ is just a synonym for $\operatorname{curl}$, and $\operatorname{curl}_z$ makes little sens to me, as there is no $z$ coordinate in the plane, and i do not feel like embedding the plane into a 3-dimensional space just to be able to use this operator.

Comment: If you aren't thinking of your vectors as 3D, then the vector-valued curl isn't defined, so you could just define curl to mean what you want.

Comment: @Karl, indeed, this would be the best solution. I just do not know if this would be acceptable. I doubt for example that it would be acceptable to define curl as divergence in 2D.