# Complex functions that is not quite analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

A complex-valued function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic if it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=0$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0$

Is there a class of functions where only one of these relations holds?

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \ne 0$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$

The real derivatives are no longer equal to zero, but the imaginaries cancel. These of course will not be analytic, but I am curious if this generalization has been the focus of study.

Comment: Complex conjugation, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a complex function, $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, the [Pólya vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Harmonic_vector_field) is based on the conjugate $\overline{f(z)}$: $\langle u(x,y),-v(x,y)\rangle$. The Cauchy-Riemann equations amount to saying that the "[scalar curl](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4328414/26369)" and [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) of the Pólya vector field are both $0$. Individually, these quantities being zero have names and significant consequences on their own:

The (scalar) curl being zero makes the vector field "irrotational". And it is often called [conservative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field), at least in nice situations with continuous second-order partial derivatives and a [simply-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) domain (the exact definition/usage of "conservative" may depend on the source).

The divergence being zero makes the vector field "incompressible" or "[solenoidal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoidal_vector_field)", which has its own nice properties.

However, I doubt that these properties of the *original* complex function are often studied, as these irrotational/incompressible vector fields don't typically arise naturally as the Pólya vector field of an easy-to-write complex function. For example, if $f(z)=\overline{z}^2$ or $f(z)=z*\overline{z}$, then neither of the Cauchy-Riemann equations holds.

Comment: I believe $f(z)=\bar{z}^2$ is analytic in the conjugate of z, so the conjugate of z would have both terms equal to zero. So I am not working with "solonoidal"/"divergence-free" functions. Thanks.

Comment: @sweetser I'm not certain I understand what you're saying. Certainly, if you compose $f(z)=\overline{z}^2$ with $z\mapsto\overline{z}$, you get the analytic $g(z)=z^2$. But I worry you meant something else that I'm missing.

Comment: If one wants to show a function is analytic in $\bar{z}$, I think you have to make the second equation a difference, so $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$.